# How to duplicate a directory and its subfolders (some empty) using cmd windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, copy, directory

I am learning to use cmd and I am starting with simple tasks. I am currently wanting to duplicate a folder and it's subfolders which currently are empty (as I use it as a template folder for future use) but I am stuck and have not found a way to do it.

I have tried copy command

```
copy "folder name" destination
```

I have also tried

```
xcopy /E "folder name" destination
```

The folder that I want to duplicate is called "TEMPLATE FOLDER" and is located in

```
"D:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\TEMPLATE FOLDER"
```

Destination folder is the same as I only want to duplicate the folder so I can rename it afterwards to the new directory I need.

I have previously been able to copy files to other locations but folder or directories seem not to work.

Thanks and I hope you can help

Comment: *Destination folder is the same as I only want to duplicate the folder* uh.. with same name for the duplicate folder? perhaps you are missing [`/S` flag](https://superuser.com/questions/1153282/using-xcopy-to-create-entire-folder-structure-including-root-folder-name-and-al)? sure you did not want to ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Hi Bagus, thanks for your comment. You are right, it did not occured me that I have to give it a different name if duplicating. And you right about using the SuperUser community. I am still learning to navigate in the stackoverflow world. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You have tried correctly. 
Make sure that the destination folder needs be different name or different folder.

from your example:
copy "folder name" destination

copy sam_data sam_data2
OR
copy sam_data /temp/sam_data2

etc.,

Comment: Hi MagicWorld, As Bagus Tesa mentioned, I am trying to duplicate a folder in the same directory so somehow I have to give it a different name. Hopes this is possible

Answer (score 0):

I researched further and found a way to duplicate my folder. Here is how I did it:

`xcopy /E "TEMPLATE FOLDER" "TEMPLATE FOLDER2"`

So there is no need to add a destination as it will automatically use the directory that I am in. And combined with the `/E` flag, it copies the empty subfolders (this seems to be a requirement).

Thanks for the help @MagicWorld and @SuperUser